# How to make constant final variables in a class like module in vb.net but in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to make all my fixed string in a variables in a one class named Constantes whith will looks like:

```
class Constantes
{
    public static sealed String var1 = "variable 1";
    public static sealed String var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

And in an other class i do this :

```
class main
{
    ...
    list.add(Constantes.var1);
    list.add(Constantes.var2);
}
```

I khnow that in the vb.net we can do this by using modules but in c# i don't khnow how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the class static and put the readonly keyword

```
public static class Constantes
{
  public static readonly string var1 = "variable 1";
  public static readonly string var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the class `static`:

```
public static class Constantes
{
  public static string var1 = "variable 1";
  public static string var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

And maybe make your members `const` if you want them constant (`const` are basically static members which you can't overwrite)

```
public static class Constantes
{
  public const string var1 = "variable 1";
  public const string var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

`readonly` is another possibility, but that's for runtime, so if they are truly constant, `const` allows for compile-time optimization (whereas `readonly` would only optimize in runtime)

Btw, for what I presume you are aiming, you should read on [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx), and see if that fits better

Comment: Sorry, changed `them` for `the class`

Comment: That won't make any difference.  (although he should do that)

Comment: @TinyOS it worked because you removed the `sealed` part... it should work even if the class was not static as @SLaks pointed out

Answer (score 3):

Use the `const` keyword, if I'm not misreading the question:

```
static class Constantes
{
    public const  String var1 = "variable 1";
    public const  String var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

Comment: . . . and make the class static?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Don't think it necessarily has to be. But sure.

Comment: It doesn't _have to be_ no, but it stamps a clear intent on the class that it should never be instantiated.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Right, agreed

Answer (score 1):

Constants are defined using the `const` keyword.

```
class Constantes
{
    public const String var1 = "variable 1";
    public const string var2 = "variable 2";
}
```

note that `static sealed` is invalid - `sealed` only applied to virtual behaviour. If you want something to never be changeable (when `const` doesn't fit, of course), use `readonly` instead.

Modules are a construct of the underlying CLR, but in C#, each assembly only contains a single module, and there are no ways to define different ones. **EDIT** however, they are *not* the same VB `Module`s. [See MSDN for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on these differences